# assembly language 8085 program to calculate sum of first 20 even numbers(8 bits)

Tags: c, assembly

An assembly language `8085` program to calculate sum of first 20 even numbers(8 bits) and store the result at location `6000` and `6001`. i tried but couldn't complete

```
MVI c,00H
MOV B, C
MOV D, 00H
NEXT:
INX, H
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a loop, because the most common reason of using assembly nowadays is speed.

The sum of `n` even numbers `2, 4, 6, ...` equals `n(n + 1)`.  (Or, of course `n(n + 1) - 2` when you start at `0, 2, 4, ...`.)

Comment: I doubt that just writing a couple of lines of code to store the value 420 at 6000:6001 will earn a passing grade.

Comment: @PaulR See my comment about educational systems above.  I agree, that would be too simple.  But implementing the formula I gave should earn him a 100% plus a public compliment.  BTW, what's the most common reason of writing assembly nowadays anyway: SPEED. Hence, using a loop is not smart.

Comment: @meaning-matters, I guess, if the theacher wanted to enforce a loop sample, he should have selected a different lesson. :) I agree, that this would be the best solution, and if the teacher didn't give explicit instructions like `... using a loop` then the answer should be accepted and applauded.

Comment: There is one problem with my solution the [8085 instruction set](http://engeletrica.sobral.ufc.br/professores/marcelo/Micro/8085_is_details.pdf) does not seem to include a multiply :-)

Comment: You can always implement multiplications with additions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First write it out in pseudo code:

```
    sum := 0                        ; init sum
    num := 2                        ; init first even number
    count := 20                     ; init loop counter
loop:
    sum := sum + num                ; accumulate sum
    num := num + 2                  ; next even number
    count := count - 1              ; decrement loop count
    IF count > 0 THEN GOTO loop     ; if loop count still positive then next num
    store sum -> 6000/6001          ; else we're done - store the result
```

From here it should be very simple to convert the pseudo code to 8085 opcodes.

Comment: The first even number is not 2 but [0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero).

Comment: @meaningmatters: strictly speaking you're correct, but I would bet that the teacher's requirement is the sum of the first twenty even numbers starting from 2.

Comment: 0 is mathemathically, not an even number. In assembler it would be identified as such though, because the first bit is not set.

Comment: @Devolus No, [0 is even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero).

Comment: @PaulR And that's precisely what sick about our educational systems: Pushing students to give the 'right' answer, instead of rewarding thinking for themselves & doing research.  It's sad that coming up with something else is bad.  I'm not agitating against you here eh :-)

Comment: @meaning-matters: OTOH being able to think about the motivation and implied meaning of a question rather than just taking it literally is an important "life skill". Of course for science/maths/engineering etc you need to be able to do both! ;-)

Comment: @meaning-matters, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To test wheter a number is even or odd in assembly is just a  matter of testing the least siginificant bit. So you need to only have a loop which increases a value and repeatedly testing this bit. If yes, then add it to your sum.

```
sum = 0
value = 0
found = 0

loop:
    if found == 20
        goto done

    if value & 1
        sum += value
        found = found + 1

   value = value +1
   goto loop

done:
    print sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get the best performance calculate the result by hand and just store it in the memory with two or so instructions.

Comment: You can go one step further and use *no* instructions - just use a data directive to put 420 at the destination address.